# How can I make alternate pixels transparent in a .png file?

Tags: graphics, transparency

I have a .png file I would like to display on Google Maps as a semi-transparent overlay. In order to do this, I would like to make approximately every other pixel in the .png file transparent. (The .png file already has a transparent "color".)

Is there a (1) free, or (2) commercial application with which this can be done without too much trouble? If so, can you point me in the right direction on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free graphics program such as Paint.NET, GIMP, or Photoshop CS2 and set the opacity to 50% for the entire image.. might be a better option than doing every other pixel.

If you really want every other pixel then you will have to do that programmatically.. so learn how to write software or cozy up to someone that knows how to.

But PNG supports a true alpha channel - not that limited transparency key stuff you have to deal with with GIF.

Comment: "*not that limited transparency key stuff you have to deal with with JPGs*" I think you mean GIF. JPEG doesn't support transparency. Otherwise, good answer. If using PNG, then adjusting overall opacity is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Indrek: all images support transparency keys.. some just some have to be coaxed into it (e.g. its an application feature instead of a format feature - either way its the same thing)